# Get Computer Name and logged user name

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I am developing an application. One of the methods needs to capture the computer name and user logged on the machine, then display both to the user. I need it to run on both Windows and Linux. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Another thing to consider. If the user runs the application on the Windows Terminal Server, which of two computers name he has to get?

Answer (score 30):

**Windows**

You can try to use `GetComputerName` and `GetUserName`, here is a example:

```
#define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767
TCHAR  infoBuf[INFO_BUFFER_SIZE];
DWORD  bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;

// Get and display the name of the computer.
if( !GetComputerName( infoBuf, &bufCharCount ) )
  printError( TEXT("GetComputerName") ); 
_tprintf( TEXT("\nComputer name:      %s"), infoBuf ); 

// Get and display the user name.
if( !GetUserName( infoBuf, &bufCharCount ) )
  printError( TEXT("GetUserName") ); 
_tprintf( TEXT("\nUser name:          %s"), infoBuf );
```

see: [GetComputerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724295(v=vs.85).aspx)
 and [GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Linux**

Use `gethostname` to get computer name(see [gethostname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html)), and `getlogin_r` to get login username. You can look more information at [man page of getlogin_r](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/getlogin_r/).
Simple usage as follows:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>

char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX];
char username[LOGIN_NAME_MAX];
gethostname(hostname, HOST_NAME_MAX);
getlogin_r(username, LOGIN_NAME_MAX);
```

Comment: About [HOST_NAME_MAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30084116/host-name-max-undefined-after-include-limits-h).

Comment: 32 KB? You only need exactly MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH+1 characters... Considering the former is only 15, 32 KB is a giant waste...

Answer (score 27):

If you can use Boost, you can do this to easily get the host name:

```
#include <boost/asio/ip/host_name.hpp>
// ... whatever ...
const auto host_name = boost::asio::ip::host_name();
```

Comment: This is the only truly cross-platform answer to this question, thanks!

Comment: Is there a Boost function to get login name instead?

Comment: This just returns a string and not a wstring. Which isn't enough for e.g. China.

Answer (score 11):

On POSIX systems you can use the [`gethostname`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gethostname) and [`getlogin`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getlogin_r) functions, both declared in `unistd.h`.

```
/*
   This is a C program (I've seen the C++ tag too late).  Converting
   it to a pretty C++ program is left as an exercise to the reader.
*/

#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main()
{
  char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX];
  char username[LOGIN_NAME_MAX];
  int result;
  result = gethostname(hostname, HOST_NAME_MAX);
  if (result)
    {
      perror("gethostname");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  result = getlogin_r(username, LOGIN_NAME_MAX);
  if (result)
    {
      perror("getlogin_r");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  result = printf("Hello %s, you are logged in to %s.\n",
                  username, hostname);
  if (result < 0)
    {
      perror("printf");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Possible output:

```
Hello 5gon12eder, you are logged in to example.com.
```

<del>This seems safer than relying on environment variables which are not always present.</del>

I'm withdrawing that last statement because

- the man page of `getlogin` actually discourages its usage in favour of `getenv("LOGIN")` and
- the `getlogin_r` call in the above program fails with `ENOTTY` when I run the program from within Emacs instead of an interactive terminal while `getenv("USER")` would have worked in both situations.

Answer (score 8):

Use `gethostname()` to get computer name, support both [windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms738527(v=vs.85).aspx/) and [linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gethostname.2.html).

Answer (score 6):

Regarding Denis's answer, note that `getenv("HOSTNAME")` for Linux [may not always work because the environment variables may not be exported to the program](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2004-July/052424.html).

Multi-platform C++ code example to fetch just the computer name (this is what worked for my Win7 and CentOS machines):

```
    char *temp = 0;
    std::string computerName;

#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
    temp = getenv("COMPUTERNAME");
    if (temp != 0) {
        computerName = temp;
        temp = 0;
    }
#else
    temp = getenv("HOSTNAME");
    if (temp != 0) {
        computerName = temp;
        temp = 0;
    } else {
        temp = new char[512];
        if (gethostname(temp, 512) == 0) { // success = 0, failure = -1
            computerName = temp;
        }
        delete []temp;
        temp = 0;
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Not only will it not always be available to the program, but there are [other deficiencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914311/get-computer-name-and-logged-user-name#comment95239774_27914342) with using it as well. Using `gethostname()` is unequivocally the better answer for Linux/POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

in Linux you can also use the following using Posix library to retrieve the real user that owns the process: 
getuid() returns the real user ID of the calling process.
see [getuid man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html)

```
#include <pwd.h>
string userName = "unknownUser";
// Structure to store user info
struct passwd p;
// Get user ID of the application
uid_t uid = getuid();

// Buffer that contains password additional information
char pwdBuffer[ourPwdBufferSize];
// Temporary structure for reentrant function
struct passwd* tempPwdPtr;

if ((getpwuid_r(uid, &p, pwdBuffer, sizeof(pwdBuffer),
        &tempPwdPtr)) == 0) {
    userName = p.pw_name;
}
```