# HOST_NAME_MAX undefined after include <limits.h>

Tags: c, hostname

I don't know why it still says HOST_NAME_MAX is implicit declaration.

Instead, I searched the web and do the following to fix it:

```
#include <netdb.h>
```

and use `MAXHOSTNAMELEN` instead of `HOST_NAME_MAX`

however, I am not very sure it this is a good way, and the reasons behind it.

Comment: `HOST_NAME_MAX` is not defined in `<limits.h>`. Why did you expect it to be?

Comment: @Keith So where is it defined ? I've checked this and it seems defined [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It *is* defined in `<limits.h>`, but not by default. (It's specified by POSIX, not by C). There's a way to specify that you want `<limits.h>` to define it, but I don't remember it off the top of my head.

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks ! I will try to search and also see what others come up with ....

Answer (score 14):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -rl '#define HOST_NAME_MAX' /usr/include
```

We can see that `HOST_NAME_MAX` is defined in:

```
/usr/include/bits/local_lim.h
```

And `local_lim.h` is included by `/usr/include/bits/posix1_lim.h`:

```
# grep -rl local_lim.h /usr/include
/usr/include/bits/posix1_lim.h
```

And `posix1_lim.h` is included by `limits.h` only if `__USE_POSIX` is defined:

```
#ifdef  __USE_POSIX
/* POSIX adds things to <limits.h>.  */
# include <bits/posix1_lim.h>
#endif
```

So if your code looks like:

```
#define __USE_POSIX
#include <limits.h>
```

You should have the `HOST_NAME_MAX` constant available.  Having said that, on my system `__USE_POSIX` appears to be defined by default.  For example, the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
#ifdef __USE_POSIX
  printf("__USE_POSIX is defined\n");
#endif
  printf("HOST_NAME_MAX: %d\n", HOST_NAME_MAX);
  return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
__USE_POSIX is defined
HOST_NAME_MAX: 64
```

Comment: I can see that it is implemented like you posted, however from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html I can see that _POSIX_C_SOURCE should be used instead of __USE_POSIX according to standard. This won't work (as it is not coded like this). Do you know why it is not coded with _POSIX_C_SOURCE?

Comment: After doing further investigation since it was not working for me while looking inside "posix1_lim.h" I found out that some stuff has been changed

**HOST_NAME_MAX** now is **_POSIX_HOST_NAME_MAX**

**LOGIN_NAME_MAX** now is **_POSIX_LOGIN_NAME_MAX** https://pastebin.com/kFmAbWcJ