# Retrieve current logged in user's name using Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I am working on a C++ application that can be run on both Windows and Unix based environments. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44152790) answer shows how to get hostname using Boost. I was wondering if there is a Boost function to also get the login name of the current user. For example, if I have `username@hostname` in Linux, then I want to retrieve `username`. I know there are techniques to do this without using Boost but I would like to know if I can do this *with* Boost. I have looked at some documentation related to the Boost library but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Can't find anything either, except maybe using Boost.Process to launch `whoami` and grab its output...

Comment: What you're almost certainly looking for is an OS-independent API call that will call the OS-dependent system call in its code. If Boost has an OS-centric library, then it will probably offer some kind of functionality like that. Otherwise, it's probably not something Boost offers.