# C++ : Error while using TEXT() function windows.h

Tags: c++, windows

I recently switched from Visual studio code to Visual studio 2019 because I wanted to download C++ package using VCPKG.

My code worked on Visual Studio Code but do not work on Visual Studio 2019, maybe because it's not the same compilator.

The code I found on a StackOverflow post ([Get Computer Name and logged user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914311/get-computer-name-and-logged-user-name/37330527)) retrieve the Computer name and the Username of a PC.

```
#define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767
TCHAR  infoBuf[INFO_BUFFER_SIZE];
DWORD  bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY pIdentStruct = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
PSID ptrSidStruct;
BOOL isMember;

Constructor::Contructor(): c_online(true), c_status("Alive"), c_master("Master IP"), c_port(80) 
{

  bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;
  if (GetComputerName(infoBuf, &bufCharCount))
  { 
    c_pc = TEXT(infoBuf);
  }

  bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;
  if (GetUserName(infoBuf, &bufCharCount))
  {
    c_user = TEXT(infoBuf);
  }
}
```

However while using the TEXT() function, I get the error "LinfoBuf not define". I don't understand this error, plus I declared infoBuf not LinfoBuf. I didn't find the GetUserName function using <windows.h> in MSND documentation but I found GetUserNameA using the header <winbase.h>

Comment: `TEXT` macro is for using with string literals, not variables. What are `c_pc` and `c_user`?

Comment: c_pc and c_user are the attribute of my class. They should store the computer name and the username of the PC. I store the value while declaring the constructor

Comment: What are the types of the attributes?

Comment: I declared c_pc and c_user as string in my class

Comment: Your VSC project probably did not define `_UNICODE`.  q.v. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/unicode-and-multibyte-character-set-mbcs-support?view=msvc-160).

Comment: You mean `std::string`?

Comment: Yes, I declared them as std::string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `Windows.h` header file, `TEXT()` is not a function, its a macro. Its purpose is to convert string/character literals at compile-time to either `wchar_t` or `char` literals, depending on whether the `UNICODE` conditional is defined or not, respectively.

Basically the definition of `TEXT` is something like this,

```cpp
#ifdef UNICODE
#define __TEXT(quote) L##quote

#else
#define __TEXT(quote) quote

#endif
#define TEXT(quote) __TEXT(quote)
```

In C++, narrow string literals are denoted as `"some string"` and wide string literals are denoted as `L"some string"`. A `##` in a macro, like what we see above, concatenates tokens together. In this case, concatenating `L` in front of the macro argument when `UNICODE` is defined. So when we say `TEXT("Hello")`, the pre-processor output is `L"Hello"` when `UNICODE` is defined, otherwise the output is `"Hello"`.

Since `infoBuf` isn't a string literal, instead its a pointer, when you use `TEXT(infoBuf)`, the compiler resolves it to be `LinfoBuf`, where the `L` comes from the macro conversion.

`GetComputerName` and `GetUserName` are macro wrappers for the `GetComputerNameA`/`GetComputerNameW` and `GetUserNameA`/`GetUserNameW` functions, respectively. These functions output the names as `char` or `wchar_t` strings. When `UNICODE` is defined, the `W` functions are used, otherwise the `A` functions are used.  So, if `c_pc` and `c_user` are containers of `char`s (like `std::string`), your best option is to use `GetComputerNameA` and `GetUserNameA` directly, eg:

```cpp
#define INFO_BUFFER_SIZE 32767
CHAR   infoBuf[INFO_BUFFER_SIZE];
DWORD  bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;

Constructor::Contructor(): c_online(true), c_status("Alive"), c_master("Master IP"), c_port(80) 
{

  bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;
  if (GetComputerNameA(infoBuf, &bufCharCount))
  { 
    c_pc = infoBuf;
  }

  bufCharCount = INFO_BUFFER_SIZE;
  if (GetUserNameA(infoBuf, &bufCharCount))
  {
    c_user = infoBuf;
  }
}
```

Comment: Re: "ASCII strings (char*)" -- the macro applies to **string literals**; it doesn't work with a `char*`. A string literal is text enclosed in double quotes. And that's the whole issue: `infoBuf` is some kind of **pointer**, so it's **not** a string literal. `"abcd"` is a string literal, and `L"abcd"` is a wide string literal. Neither one is a pointer. Since a string literal is an array of `char` (or `wchar_t` if it's a wide string literal), in most contexts it **decays** into a pointer to its first element. But it is not a pointer.

Comment: And note that `std::string`s are **not** "containers of `char*`s". They hold `char` elements, not `char*` elements.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yup sorry my bad. Got a little confused with the terminology.